# How to add css and js files on node pages independent of the theme?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, themes

I am using display suite to display a full node of type 'Article'. I want to add some css and js on the page containing the article node, though the adding of these can't be dependent on the themeing. So I cannot use the template.php file

How would I be able to do this ?

Comment: are you looking to theme your Article type node independently? have a look this http://drupal.org/node/17565

Comment: I rather not work with tpl files for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new module and put it in: /sites/all/modules/custom

The module structure and files would look like this:

```
ahelper/
ahelper/css/article_node.css
ahelper/js/article_node.js
ahelper/ahelper.info
ahelper/ahelper.module
```

ahelper/ahelper.info

```
core = "7.x"
name = "Article Helper"
project = "ahelper"
version = "7.x-1.0"
```

ahelper/ahelper.module

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view()
 */
function ahelper_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // if node is an article, and we're looking at a full page view
  if ($node->type == 'article' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    // then add this javascript file
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ahelper') .'/js/article_node.js');
    // and add this css file
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'ahelper') .'/css/article_node.css');
  }
}
```

Then just enable the module.  You can play around with the node_view hook.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module and include your js and css files using the functions drupal_add_js and drupal_add_css. You can call them either in your custom module's hook_init or hook_nodeapi (or Node Api Hooks in Drupal 7) depending on how you want to include your files. These functions get called regardless of what theme your using.

References:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css

Comment: Myes, I was looking in the same direction :). In the module, I would wnat to define some templates I am using in my theme at the moment. These tpl files are view overriding: lik -> block--views--article-images--block.tpl using the  hook_theme_registry_alter function. Can you help out with that ?

Comment: ok, I was able to put the templates in my module folder. THX for the help :)